# What is my misunderstanding in Wick's theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator, wick-theorem

Trying to understand Wick's theorem, I took most of my knowledge from the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem). The statement is that given the definition of normal ordering of operators $A,B,C,\ldots$ any product of those operators can be expressed as
\begin{align} ABCDEF\ldots=\;&:ABCDEF\ldots: \\\\ &+\sum_{\mathrm{singles}} :A^\bullet B^\bullet CDEF\ldots: \\\\ &+\sum_{\mathrm{doubles}} :A^\bullet B^{\bullet\bullet} C^{\bullet\bullet}D^\bullet EF\ldots: \\\\ &+\ldots \end{align}

where $:ABCDEF\ldots:$ is the normal ordering of the operators and $A^\bullet B^\bullet\equiv AB-:AB:$ is their contraction.

**Problem:**
Consider the quantum harmonic oscillator with ladder operators $a,a^\dagger$ and $N=a^\dagger a$ with commutation relations $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ and $[N,a]=-a$ and $[N,a^\dagger]=a^\dagger$. I am interested in changing the order of terms like $N^na$. Therefore I define the normal ordering as $:Na:=aN$ and hence $N^\bullet a^\bullet=[N,a]=-a$.

Now apply Wick's theorem to the term $N^na$ and we find
\begin{align}
N^na =& :N^na:+:N^{n-1}N^\bullet a^\bullet:+:N^{n-2}N^\bullet Na^\bullet:+\ldots \\\\
=&:N^na:+n:N^{n-1}N^\bullet a^\bullet: \\\\
=&aN^n-naN^{n-1}
\end{align}
where I made use of the fact that only contractions involving $a$ survive so that we only get terms with single contractions.

Apparently this is not the correct result, as a simple example with $n=2$ shows
\begin{align}
N^2a=&aN^2+[N^2,a] \\\\
&=aN^2+N[N,a]+[N,a]N\\\\
&=aN^2-Na-aN \\\\
&=aN^2-2aN-[N,a] \\\\
&=aN^2-2aN+a
\end{align} where I used the fact that $[A^2,B]=A[A,B]+[A,B]A$. This result differs from the one obtained using Wick's theorem: $N^2a=aN^2-2aN$.

I am sure that the mistake lies in my understanding how to apply the theorem. Can someone point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) assumes that the contraction $N^{\bullet}a^{\bullet}$ belongs to the [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29) of the pertinent operator algebra, which is not true in OP's case.

Comment: Thanks. Is there by chance a more general theorem, that lets me resolve the situation?

Comment: Hi Suppenkasper: You may enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400227/2451) Phys.SE post.