# Proof of Wick's theorem for general Gaussian states

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator, density-operator, wick-theorem

For boson modes $a^\dagger_i, a_i$, consider the density matrix which is an exponential of quadratic operators in $a^\dagger_i$ and $a_i$:
$$\rho = e^{-H_{ij} a^\dagger_i a_j + (K_{ij} a^\dagger_i a^\dagger_j + h.c.)}.$$
Here, $H_{ij}$ and $K_{ij}$ are matrices and Einstein summation convention is assumed.

Question: How can one prove the Wick's theorem
$$\langle O X_1 \cdots X_{2n}\rangle = \sum_{\sigma\in S_{2n} \textrm{ contraction}}\langle O X_{\sigma(1)} X_{\sigma(2)} \rangle \cdots \langle O X_{\sigma(2n-1)} X_{\sigma(2n)} \rangle $$
for the above density matrix, where $X_i$ is linear in boson operators and $O$ is an arbitrary operator ordering?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400227/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451 and links therein.