# Kardar "Statistical Physics of Fields" expectation value identity

Tags: statistical-mechanics, path-integral, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

In Eq. (5.7) of his book "Statistical Physics of Fields", M. Kardar proposes the identity

$$
\langle e^{\sum_i a_ix_i} \rangle
=\exp{\left[\sum_{ij}\frac{a_ia_j}{2}\langle x_ix_j \rangle\right]}\tag{5.7}
$$

where the expectation value is taken with respect to a set $\{x_i\}$ of Gaussian distributed variables. I attempted to prove this as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle e^{\sum_i a_ix_i} \rangle
&\propto\prod_i\int dx_i\,e^{a_ix_i}\,e^{-b_ix_i^2}\\
&=\prod_i\int dx_i\,\exp{\left[-b_i\left(x_i^2-\frac{a_i}{b_i}\,x_i+\frac{a_i^2}{4b_i^2}\right)+\frac{a_i^2}{4b_i}\right]}\\
&=\prod_ie^{\frac{a_i^2}{4b_i}}\int dx_i \exp{\left[-b_i\left(x_i-\frac{a_i}{2b_i}\right)^2\right]}\\
&=\prod_i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b_i}}\,e^{\frac{a_i^2}{4b_i}}.
\end{align}
$$

The product $\prod_i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b_i}}$ will disappear once the distribution is properly normalized; ie.

$$
\langle e^{\sum_i a_ix_i} \rangle
=\prod_i e^{\frac{a_i^2}{4b_i}}
$$

On the other hand

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x_i^2\rangle
&\propto\prod_i\int dx_i\,x_i^2\,e^{-b_ix_i^2}\\
&=\prod_{j\ne i}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b_j}}\int dx_i\,x_i^2\,e^{-b_ix_i^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2b_i}\prod_j\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b_j}}
\end{align}
$$

and similarly

$$
\langle x_i^2\rangle
=\frac{1}{2b_i}.
$$

Combining these expressions:

$$
\langle e^{\sum_i a_ix_i} \rangle
=\prod_i\exp{\left[\frac{a_i}{2}\,\langle x_i^2\rangle\right]}
=\exp{\left[\sum_i\frac{a_i}{2}\,\langle x_i^2\rangle\right]}
$$

which agrees with Kardar's result, modulo the cross-terms. By the even-odd symmetry of the integrand, I understand that these cross-terms $\langle x_i x_j\rangle$ will vanish for $i\ne j$, and that Kardar is therefore free to add them to his identity with impunity, but I don't understand the point of doing so. Is there a reason Kardar is including these terms, or have I made a mistake in my derivation?

Comment: Kadar does not assume the $x_i$ are mutually independent while you do it. Saying the expected value of a product is the product of expected values requires independence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Eq. (5.7) is often given in this form. It is equivalent to [Isserlis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem), which is one version of [Wick's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400227/2451).
2. Perhaps Kardar is deriving (5.7) from the fact that (i) a linear combination $x=\sum_ia_ix_i$ of Gaussian distributed variables $x_i$ is again a Gaussian distributed variable, and (ii) that $\langle e^x\rangle = e^{\langle x^2\rangle/2}$.